# Flutter. Using a builder that returns a dynamic but actually needs a Future<T>

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I am trying to use the below sharedPreferenceBuilder by Simon Lightfoot.

```
class SharedPreferencesBuilder<T> extends StatelessWidget {
    final String pref;
    final AsyncWidgetBuilder<T> builder;

     const SharedPreferencesBuilder({
        Key key,
        @required this.pref,
        @required this.builder,
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder<T>(
            future: _future(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<T> snapshot) {
                return builder(context, snapshot);
            });
    }

    Future<T> _future() async {
        return (await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).get(pref); <-------- Here is the issue
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the _future() function is returning a dynamic type instead of a Future. I tried putting `as Future<T>` at the end of the return but it still did not work.

Is there any way I can convert a dynamic type into a Future?

I have also been explicit and swapped the `<T>` for `<String>` but that hasn't worked either.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Try returning `(Future.value(SharedPreferences.getInstance()).get(pref) as dynamic));`
Also using await and Future is redundant. If you want it to be a future you have to call the method with `_future().then((value) => {value here will be the value of your sharedPref.get()})`. Basically, I'd remove Future.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Unfortunately I'm still receiving the same error "The return type 'dynamic' isn't a 'FutureOr<T>', as required by the closure's context".

Comment: I tested your code and it works, no errors.

Comment: ok thanks. must be something wrong my end then.